# Appropriate hashing function to hash random binary strings

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, hash

i have an two arrays : char data1[length]  where length is a multiple of 8 i.e length can be 8, 16,24 ... The array contains binary data read from a file that is open in binary mode. I will keep reading from the file and everytime i read i will store the read value in a hash table. The disterbution of this binary data has a random distribution. I would like to hash each array and store them in a hash table in order to be able to look for the char with the specific data again. What would be a good hashing function to achive this task. Thanks

Please note that i am writing this in c++ and c so any language you choose to provide a solution for would be great.

Comment: Why don't you just take *Berkeley DB4* and let that library handle all the details?

Comment: And what will you do about hash collisions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data that you read is 8 bytes long and really distributed randomly, and your hashcode needs to be 32 bits, what about this:

```
uint32_t hashcode(const unsigned char *data) {
  uint32_t hash = 0;
  hash ^= get_uint32_le(data + 0);
  hash ^= get_uint32_le(data + 4);
  return hash;
}

uint32_t get_uint32_le(const unsigned char *data) {
  uint32_t value = 0;
  value |= data[0] << 0;
  value |= data[1] << 8;
  value |= data[2] << 16;
  value |= data[3] << 24;
  return value;
}
```

If you need more speed, this code can probably made a lot faster if you can guarantee that `data` is always properly aligned to be interpreted as an `const uint32_t *`.

Comment: As mentioned in the question the length is an number that is a multiple of 8. How can i extend your ideas to mutliple of 8s and not just 8 bytes?

Comment: By adding a `size_t datalen` parameter to the hashcode function. When you have understood the code, this is a trivial thing to do. I even wrote the code so that it can be extended easily.

Comment: +1: although if the data is truly random (I assume we really mean "uniform" here), you don't even need to xor; just use the first 32 bits as your hash.

Comment: this method seems to alter the data eventhough you have the const in there. I tried it and it kept on changing my data

Comment: I doubt that. The code clearly has only read operations, and I'm not using any cast to cast away the `const`. The only things I change atr local variables. If you can prove that the data has indeed changed, I will be very interested in that.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used [MurmurHash3](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) in one of my projects.

Pros:

- It is *fast*. *Very fast*.
- It supposedly has a low collision rate.

Cons:

- It's not suitable for cryptography applications.
- It's not standardized in any shape or form.
- It's not portable to non-x86 platforms. However, it's small enough that you should be able to port it if you really need to - I was able to port it to Java, although that's not nearly the same thing.

It's a good possibility for use in e.g. a fast hash-table implementation...

Comment: I am also want to implement on my project, Actually i want to hash string in to binary via MurmurHash. But Murmur hash algorithm also generates negative hash value. so i am facing problem with. I implement same code as you mention above.
it you have any hashing algorithm with gives similar hash value for similar message. For example if there is change in one character only then less change in hash value.